# Event Scheduler in mysql not working

Tags: mysql

I worte the below mention scheduler which delete some data every minute whose date_created is four days back to current date but delete data once when the file is import in mysql but after that doesnt work for me. Kindly tell me what the problem with the scheduler.

```
use mydatabase;
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS  noti_event ;
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = OFF;
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
create EVENT IF NOT EXISTS noti_event ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS CURDATE() + '12:00:00'

DO
   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
   DELETE FROM user_noti WHERE noti_id in (Select id from noti where date_created <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 DAY));
   DELETE FROM noti_read_by WHERE noti_id in (Select id from noti where date_created <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 DAY));
   DELETE FROM associated_add WHERE id  in (Select id from noti where date_created <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 DAY));
   DELETE FROM noti WHERE date_created <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 DAY) ;
   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
;
```

Comment: When the Event Scheduler is ON, the event scheduler thread is listed in the output of `SHOW PROCESSLIST` as a daemon process, and its `state` is represented as `Waiting for next activation` or something like that. Check if your scheduler is listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set ON COMPLETION PRESERVE option, e.g. -

```
CREATE EVENT event1
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' MINUTE
  STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
  DO 
BEGIN
END
```

Comment: If I use **END** at the end of the event scheduler, then it return an error `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1
`

Comment: I added **ON COMPLETION PRESERVE** in my scheduler but didn't run `EVERY '1' MINUTE`

Comment: Was it executed at least one time?

Comment: when i import file it execute all the commands but after that it didn't work for me

Comment: Can you show result of `SHOW CREATE EVENT event_name;` command (Create Event column)?

Comment: i run the command which give result **Create Event** `CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `notification_event` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 SECOND STARTS '2013-12-03 12:35:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` but didn't rest of query and when i use END in the event secheduler it gave syntax error which i mention in the above mention link

Comment: If event contains more then one statement, then you need to use BEGIN..END clause, and DELIMITER command - if your client supports it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42390/discussion-between-rahul-and-devart)